# How do I call a QCheckBox inside a different class in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application with 2 windows. After a certain event in window #1 I want to uncheck a checkbox in window #2 using a pyqtSignal if it is possible.
This is what I have so far:
2nd window:

```
class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.box = QCheckBox('some text', self)

    def disable_box(self):
        self.box.setChecked(False)
```

in the main window:

```
win2 = AnotherWindow()
worker.box_update.connect(win2.disable_box())
```

I get an error after this:
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: use `worker.box_update.connect(win2.disable_box)`

Comment: thanks error is gone, and if put print("test") in the disable_box function, it prints fine, but the checkbox is not reacting to anything. setChecked, setDisable I tried these so far and nothing.

Comment: Without a [MRE] it is impossible to help you.